# What is wrong htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following htaccess rules but I dont know how to make it work:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^game/([^/]*)$ index.php?cash=$1
```

The following is the screen shot of my folders structure:

[image]

Can someone tell me how to get it to work? I have also tried:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php([^/]*)$ index.php?cash=$1
```

The URL that I want to display is: http://localhost/biteep/game/100 while the URL that I want the browser to go to is http://localhost/biteep/game?cash=100

Comment: Note that you use lowercase `biteep` in your URL while you have uppercase `Biteep` in the directory structure. This works because you are on Windows, but it will fail on OSX and Linux.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 1):

Try to put a rewrite base into your .htaccess:

```
RewriteBase /biteep/
```

And this route should be enough:

```
RewriteRule ^game\/(\d+)$ index.php?cash=$1
```

Comment: I have put this in:
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /biteep/
RewriteRule ^game\/(\d+)$ index.php?cash=$1

Does not work

Comment: Try to add a [L] after the rewrite rule like this: "RewriteRule ^game\/(\d+)$ index.php?cash=$1 [L]"

Comment: Also note that if you want support for a trailing slash, i.e. for http://localhost/biteep/game/100/ you might use `RewriteRule ^game\/(\d+)(\/?)$ index.php?cash=$1 [L]`

Answer (score 0):

So it works when I do this

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ index.php?cash=$1
```